# Conjugate subgroups by permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, classical-groups

Is the following statement true or false?

In $G=\operatorname{GL}_{n}(\textbf{C})$, two elementary abelian $2$-subgroups $X$ and $Y$ of $G$ whose generators are all diagonal matrices are conjugate if and only if there is a permutation matrix $P$ s.t. $PX=YP$.

I'm aware that the right implies the left. For the other direction, it is true when $X$ and $Y$ has only one generator because the numbers of $-1$ on the diagonals of the generators are equal. What about when we have more than one generator? Are there cases where $X,Y$ can only be conjugate by a non-permutation matrix? I checked some examples and didn't see such a case. Thank you.

Comment: Are asking about subgroups of ${\rm GL}_n({\mathbb C})$ or ${\rm PGL}_n({\mathbb C})$? The elements of ${\rm PGL}_n({\mathbb C})$ are not matrices.

Comment: OK. We can work in $\operatorname{GL}_{n}(\textbf{C})$. I've made the change. Thank you.

Comment: I feel like (representation-theory) is an applicable tag, though not sure which tag I'd replace it with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the characters of an abelian group $A$ are $\chi_1,\cdots,\chi_k$. Then any $A$-rep $V$ has an isotypical decomposition $V=V_1\oplus\cdots\oplus V_k$
where each $V_i$ is a sum of irreps corresponding to $\chi_i$. The components are weight spaces, i.e. $V_i=\{v\in V\mid av=\chi_i(a)v~~\forall a\in A\}$. If $V=\mathbb{C}^n$ and $A$ is diagonal, in fact

$$ V_i=\mathrm{span}\{e_j\mid ae_j=\chi_i(a)e_j~~\forall a\in A\}, $$

where $e_1,\cdots,e_n$ are the basis coordinate vectors. To this, we can associate a partition $\Pi$ of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$, where the $i$th block consists of all $j$ for which $e_j\in V_i$.

A conjugate representation ${}^g\!A=gAg^{-1}$ of $A\,$ ($g\in\mathrm{GL}_n\mathbb{C}$) has isotypic decomposition $gV_1\oplus\cdots\oplus gV_k$, with $\chi_i$ associated to each $gV_i$ again. Thus, the component dimensions are unchanged, which means if ${}^g\!A$ is also diagonal then it too has an associated partition $\Pi'$ and of the same shape (i.e. block sizes) as $\Pi$.

Since $S_n$ acts transitively on ordered partitions of the same shape, there is a permutation $\sigma$ for which $\Pi'=P\Pi$, and if $P$ is the associated permutation matrix then ${}^g\!A={}^P\!A$ because both groups act the same on all standard basis vectors.

Comment: Appreciate your time. At the beginning of the answer, should it be $V=V_{1}\oplus... V_{k}$? Thx!

Comment: Also, I suppose isotypic and isotypical mean the same? I'm not familiar with the definition of this. But based on the text written, I suppose it means this: the irreps $\beta_{i}$ of an abelian group are all 1-dimsional. So $V=V_{1}\oplus..V_{k}$ where each $V_{i}$ corresponds to $\chi_{i}$ which is a sum of the irreducible reps isomorphic to $\beta_{i}$?

Comment: I prefer the notation $a_1+\cdots+a_n$ over $a_1+\cdots a_n$ for summations, and the same for direct sums. Yes isotypic/isotypical mean the same thing. Each $V_i$ is a sum of irreducible reps with character $\chi_i$.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the subscript should be $k$ or $n$? Because later on it was $gV_{1}\oplus .. \oplus gV_{k}$ again...

Comment: Also, it was a partition of $n$. I got a bit confused by the subscripts. Sorry.

Comment: Oh yes there should be $k$ summands not $n$, that's right. Fixed.

Comment: Sorry to trouble with a quick question. In the answer, do we require the representation to be faithful anywhere? Thx.

Comment: You defined $A$ and its conjugate (you called them $X$ and $Y$) as subgroups of $GL_n\Bbb C$, so aren't they automatically faithful? I suppose you could replace $A$ by a (not necessarily faithful) representation and an equivalent rep on the same space, in which case we are not using faithfulness.